# Create svg with selectable text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, svg

I am new to designing. I have photoshop and illustrator with me. I need to create an svg where I can be able to select the text inside it. As shown in this [example](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedTextFills/index17.html) where the text is selectable.

Currently, If I save a text svg in illustrator, the text is converting in to image. (*I am unable to select the text*)

Comment: What have you tried? Could you explain what your export / `svg` settings are? Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent I just ran with default settings (_as I don't have much knowledge on this softwares_). I just need to be able to select the text inside the generated svg.

Comment: That is already valuable information, thanks.

Comment: There is a problem with your question. The example is not very conductive as it shows a clipping mask and that different form what you ask. (but clipping mask with selectable text is also possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Illustrator you can Save as .svg. In the SVG option panel, for type, you have to choose "SVG". The other option, "Convert to outline", will convert you text into a vector shape.

You can drag you .svg file into the browser and check if it is selectable.

Then, in  a text editor, you can edit the text from your SVG file, or style it with CSS.

[image: Illustrator SVG options]

[image: SVG file in browser]

[image: SVG file in a text editor (Sublime Text)]

Comment: But that will not preserve the text inside the svg. It will make the text also as in image format.

Comment: That's Great:) Never tested that before @Dan Kraepelin

Comment: I've attached some pictures. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your bookmark organization is awesome.

Comment: Haha. Thank you. Branding recognition in action.